Unable to get the payment method from a Stripe session
Given a session ID, how can I get the payment method that was entered? (The session used the setup mode, and the form is embedded on my page.)
// Get the session object
Stripe.Checkout.SessionService sessionService = new();
Stripe.Checkout.Session session = await sessionService.GetAsync(id);

According to the documentation:

After you have retrieved the Session object, get the value of the setup_intent key, which is the ID for the SetupIntent created during the Checkout Session. A SetupIntent is an object used to set up the customer’s bank account information for future payments.

However, the Stripe.Checkout.Session class has no setup-intent property (and it isn't a valid property name). It has a SetupIntent property, but this is an object and not a string, and for me, it's value is null.
Does anyone have an example of doing this other than the documentation cited above?

When you create a Checkout Session in setup mode, it should generate a SetupIntent and include the SetupIntent Id in the response. This only turns into a SetupIntent object if you expand the setup_intent property on your Create Checkout Session API call.
Now this SetupIntent won't have a PaymentMethod, but it will, after you confirm that SetupIntent, aka paid on the Checkout Session hosted page. You will then received a setup_intent.succeeded webhook event, and can inspect its payment_method property. Again, this turns into a Payment Method object if you call Retrieve SetupIntent API and expand the payment_method property.
